# How to change the default weather provider in Windows 8 Weather Modern UI app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui, live-tiles, weather

The Modern UI Weather app in Windows 8/8.1 uses 3 weather forecast providers - WDT, Foreca & AccuWeather. The default is WDT, and its info about the current weather conditions is displayed on the app's live tile. However, its data are enough incorrect - at least, for my home city - so I'd like to change it to something else. How can I change the default weather provider to Foreca in this Modern UI app?

Comment: Why not use the [ForecaWeather](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/forecaweather/fff8e287-ebe7-46d2-936b-84a6727ad0c7/m/ROW) app?

Comment: @Calvin, I do know about this app, but I'm asking about the native Weather app. I like the way it displays the Foreca forecast alongside with the AccuWeather forecast so I can see both, and I like the animated precipitation and cloud maps in it.

Comment: @Calvin, BTW, I cannot install that ForecaWeather app. I see the installation status as pending, but the app isn't installed. Reboot also doesn't help.